# Log user activities in C# form application

Tags: c#, logging

In my form application , I have two buttons. When user hits the button, it updates in the SQL.

So I want to log the number what user enters in the textbox in the separate txt file(logs) what user is entering in the table.

please check the below code to undesrtsand what my application is doing

```
private void button_StatusChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data source = Test; Initial Catalog = TableName; user id = sa;pwd = 12345678 ");
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really need to change", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        this.Close();

    SqlCommand updateCommand = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
    sqlcon.Open();
    updateCommand.CommandText = " update dbo.TableTBL set ColumName = '" + comboBox_statusChange.Text + "' where TId = '" + textBox_cNumber.Text + "'";

    string resultStatus = ((string)updateCommand.ExecuteScalar());
    updateCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    MessageBox.Show(" Status Changed Successfully");
    sqlcon.Close();

}
```

Comment: Didn't notice your question

Comment: I want to enable login of my user activity such as what number he eter in the textbox

Comment: Do you mean a value in the "textBox_cNumber"?

Comment: What customer enters in the textbox should be logged in text file

Comment: So you are looking for the code that opens file and write some values in it?

Comment: ya some sort of example

Comment: Post you sample code. Also you can use advanced logging solutions like log4net

Comment: You don't really have a table called `TableTBL` do you?

Answer (score 1):

```
//very simple log to file
File.AppendAllText("filepath_here.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + textBox_cNumber.Text + "\r\n");
```

Comment: This won't work. `File.Create` will create the file and return a `FileStream` you can use to do stuff to the file, but you aren't closing. So you'll get an IOException on the next line. You just need the `File.AppendAllText` line -> it creates the file for you, you don't need to call `File.Create`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Arran! Hadn't tested it properly. Fixed.